# HELP needed with DOM error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, error

```
jquery.min.js:206 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.test.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Getting this error. Can anyone help?

Comment: I got same error for welpixel quickview on product detail page.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue. it was just custom added jQuery issue please check custom jQuery added by you with proper class or id used or not.

thanks